# Expand dataset long ways using start and stop dates

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
      ID  RECN EXSTDAT    EXSTPDAT   EXONGO EX2LD DOSEA DOSFRM  DOSFRQ ADURN STUDYST    EXSTDAY EXSTPDAY
   <int> <dbl> <date>     <date>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <date>       <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1     1 2022-07-08 2022-07-27      0     0    50 Capsule QD        19 2022-07-08       0       19
 2     1     2 2022-07-28 2022-08-14      0     1    50 Capsule QD        17 2022-07-08      20       37
 3     2     2 2022-06-09 2022-06-09      0     0    50 Capsule QD         0 2022-06-09       0        0
 4     2     1 2022-06-14 2022-08-02      0     0    50 Capsule QD        49 2022-06-09       5       54
 5     2     3 2022-08-03 2022-08-14      0     0     0 Capsule QD        11 2022-06-09      55       66
 6     2     5 2022-08-15 2022-09-26      0     0    50 Capsule QD        42 2022-06-09      67      109
 7     2     4 2022-09-27 2023-02-15      1     0   100 Capsule QD       141 2022-06-09     110      251
 8     3     1 2022-06-30 2022-08-03      0     1    50 Capsule QD        34 2022-06-30       0       34
 9     4     1 2022-08-24 2022-10-04      0     1   100 Capsule QD        41 2022-08-24       0       41
10     5     1 2022-12-30 2023-01-19      0     1   200 Capsule QD        20 2022-12-30       0       20
```

I would like to generate an observation for each day between the intervals of EXSTDAY and EXSTPDAY, keeping ID, DOSEA, DOSFRM, and DOSFRQ. Below is an example of the desired results for up to study day (STDAY <= 8) for ID 1 & 2:

```
ID  DOSEA   DOSFRM  DOSFRQ  STDAY
1   50      Capsule QD      0
1   50      Capsule QD      1
1   50      Capsule QD      2
1   50      Capsule QD      3
1   50      Capsule QD      4
1   50      Capsule QD      5 
1   50      Capsule QD      6
1   50      Capsule QD      7 
1   50      Capsule QD      8
2   50      Capsule QD      0
2   50      Capsule QD      5
2   50      Capsule QD      6
2   50      Capsule QD      7
2   50      Capsule QD      8
```

I have no idea where to start, so any advice is much appreciated!

`dput` of original dataset:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), RECN = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 
3, 5, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), EXSTDAT = structure(c(19181, 19201, 19152, 
19157, 19207, 19219, 19262, 19173, 19228, 19356, 19356, 19377, 
19303, 19326, 19363, 19216, 19220, 19346, 19362, 19365, 19264, 
19277, 19282, 19219, 19226, 19310, 19345, 19351, 19352, 19354, 
19355, 19370), class = "Date"), EXSTPDAT = structure(c(19200, 
19218, 19152, 19206, 19218, 19261, 19403, 19207, 19269, 19376, 
19376, 19403, 19325, 19328, 19383, 19216, 19361, 19366, 19364, 
19403, 19275, 19281, 19403, 19225, 19226, 19338, 19350, 19351, 
19353, 19354, 19369, 19370), class = "Date"), EXONGO = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), EX2LD = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), DOSEA = c(50, 50, 50, 50, 0, 50, 100, 50, 100, 200, 
200, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
50, 0, 100, 200, 0, 200, 0, 200, 0), DOSFRM = c("Capsule", "Capsule", 
"Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", 
"Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Tablet", 
"Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Tablet", "Tablet", 
"Tablet", "Tablet", "Tablet", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", 
"Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule", "Capsule"
), DOSFRQ = c("QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", 
"QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", 
"QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", "QD", 
"QD", "QD"), ADURN = c(19, 17, 0, 49, 11, 42, 141, 34, 41, 20, 
20, 26, 22, 2, 20, 0, 141, 20, 2, 38, 11, 4, 121, 6, 0, 28, 5, 
0, 1, 0, 14, 0), STUDYST = structure(c(19181, 19181, 19152, 19152, 
19152, 19152, 19152, 19173, 19228, 19356, 19356, 19377, 19303, 
19303, 19363, 19216, 19216, 19216, 19216, 19216, 19264, 19264, 
19264, 19219, 19219, 19310, 19345, 19345, 19345, 19345, 19345, 
19345), class = "Date"), EXSTDAY = c(0, 20, 0, 5, 55, 67, 110, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 4, 130, 146, 149, 0, 13, 18, 0, 7, 
0, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10, 25), EXSTPDAY = c(19, 37, 0, 54, 66, 109, 
251, 34, 41, 20, 20, 26, 22, 25, 20, 0, 145, 150, 148, 187, 11, 
17, 139, 6, 7, 28, 5, 6, 8, 9, 24, 25)), row.names = c(NA, -32L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want one row in your data frame for each day that each subject was participating in your study. If that's the case then you can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(ID, DOSEA, DOSFRM, DOSFRQ,
          STDAY = as.numeric(if(EXSTPDAT - EXSTDAT == 0) EXSTDAT - STUDYST else
                    seq(EXSTPDAT - EXSTDAT) + EXSTDAT - STUDYST - 1)) 
#># A tibble: 861 x 5
#>      ID DOSEA DOSFRM  DOSFRQ STDAY
#>   <int> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1     1    50 Capsule QD         0
#> 2     1    50 Capsule QD         1
#> 3     1    50 Capsule QD         2
#> 4     1    50 Capsule QD         3
#> 5     1    50 Capsule QD         4
#> 6     1    50 Capsule QD         5
#> 7     1    50 Capsule QD         6
#> 8     1    50 Capsule QD         7
#> 9     1    50 Capsule QD         8
#>10     1    50 Capsule QD         9
#># ... with 851 more rows
#># i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Marked as the answer. Thanks!

Added a "+1" after `EXSTPDAT` in the `else` statement to be inclusive of the stop date (`EXSTPDAT`). Revised code reads as follows: `seq(EXSTPDAT + 1 - EXSTDAT) + EXSTDAT - STUDYST - 1))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a `seq`uence between `EXSTDAY` and `EXSTPDAY` one approach could be using `map2` from `purrr` as follows. The final `select` will indicate which columns you wish to retain in the end.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(STDAY = map2(EXSTDAY, EXSTPDAY, seq)) %>%
  unnest(STDAY) %>%
  select(ID, DOSEA, DOSFRM, DOSFRQ, STDAY)
```

**Output**

```
      ID DOSEA DOSFRM  DOSFRQ STDAY
   <int> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <int>
 1     1    50 Capsule QD         0
 2     1    50 Capsule QD         1
 3     1    50 Capsule QD         2
 4     1    50 Capsule QD         3
 5     1    50 Capsule QD         4
 6     1    50 Capsule QD         5
 7     1    50 Capsule QD         6
 8     1    50 Capsule QD         7
 9     1    50 Capsule QD         8
10     1    50 Capsule QD         9
# … with 877 more rows
```